# Cassandra driver error in installing

Tags: python, python-3.x, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am getting following error in installing Cassandra driver for python.

```
Command "c:\python33\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\
\users\\vmasama\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-we10p7\\cassandra-driver\\setup
.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n
', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\vmasama\appdata\local\te
mp\pip-olh8j5-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --co
mpile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\vmasama\appdata\local\temp\pip-build
-we10p7\cassandra-driver\
```

Any one have any idea about this ? What am i missing ?

Following errors were also there when i run **pip install cassandra-driver**

> Failed building wheel for cassandra-driver
>   Failed cleaning build dir
>   for cassandra-driver

python version : 3.3

Answer (score 2):

I tried it in an environment missing compiler paths and observed something similar. I think it's a problem in setuptools error handling when it doesn't find what it's expecting. The easiest way I've found is to use the VS Command Prompt shortcut installed with Visual Studio:

> Perhaps the easiest way to do this is to run the build/install from a Visual Studio Command Prompt (a shortcut installed with Visual Studio that sources the appropriate environment and presents a shell).

http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/installation.html#windows-installation-notes